# returning String[ ] array in java method without commas

Tags: java

I am solving a problem in `TopCoder` where I need to write a method which must return `String[]`. This is my method, and its working without any error:

```
    public static String[] decode(String encoded)
{
    char[] test = encoded.toCharArray();
    int[] decode_arr = new int[test.length];
    String[] result = new String[2];
    boolean flag= false;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        flag = false;
        decode_arr[0] = i;
        decode_arr[1] = Character.getNumericValue(test[0])-decode_arr[0];

        for(int x=2;x<test.length;x++)
        {
            decode_arr[x] = Character.getNumericValue(test[x-1]) - decode_arr[x-2]-decode_arr[x-1];
            if(decode_arr[x]>1 || decode_arr[x]<0)
                flag=true;
        }
        if(!flag)
            result[i] = Arrays.toString(decode_arr);
        else
            result[i] = "NONE";

        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decode_arr));
        decode_arr = null;
        decode_arr = new int[test.length];
    }

    return result;

}
```

Now the problem is the compiler expects values without commas, for instance if the output is:

`"01101001101101001101001001001101001",
  "10110010110110010110010010010110010"`

What I do obtain is:

`[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Am I missing any common tweaks or am I supposed to trim the output and submit it the way it's supposed to be? Kindly help!

Comment: My guess is that `Arrays.toString(decode_arr);` is not the right choice. I suggest building a `char[]` of the characters expected and turn this into a `String`

Comment: Is the output always going to be 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what `Arrays.toString()` does. Show's the group of values clearly the same way as List. In case of:

```
int[] array = {11, 2}; // printed as "112" afterwards
```

..you cannot clearly see if it's the array of `[11, 2]`, or `[1, 12]` or only `[112]`.

However if you desire that kind of output, try to replace all unwanted characters with an empty character:

```
String out = Arrays.toString(array).replace(", ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

In case of having `[]` characters as some of values, I recommend you better this safe way:

```
String arrayAsString = Arrays.toString(array);
String out = arrayAsString.substring(1,arrayAsString.length()-1).replace(", ","");
```